# IDX directory for splunk

Tags: deployment, splunk, idx

Where to find IDX directory for app while deployment in SPLUNK . I tried to find it in opt/splunk/etc/shcluster/apps

Comment: "IDX" is not a directory name normally used by Splunk apps.  From where did you get that name?  What app are you trying to deploy?

Comment: Deploying application in searchhead cluster

Comment: That answers none of my questions.  Which app?  Please quote the text that uses "IDX directory".  I need more information before I can help you.

Comment: acn-custom-log-monitoring is the name of the app in staging environment place idx folder in apps directory from indexer . This is what I was asked by my team

Answer (score 0):

Your team is not being very helpful.  :-)  "IDX" is a common abbreviation for "index" or "indexer", but there is never a directory by that name.

Often, an app that is already installed in a staging environment just gets copied from there straight into Production.  That can change depending on the architecture of the two environments, however.

The usual method for installing an app is to explode the tarball into the $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps directory and restart Splunk.  Clusters have a different procedure so let us know if you have one.  See the docs at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/Overview/Distributedinstall